# Bootstrap Navbar not collapsing properly in Tumblr?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tumblr

The Navbar isn't responsive when collapsed, and won't unfold.

http://whitneymisch.tumblr.com

I called jquery, here is the code:

```
{block:HasPages}
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            {block:Pages}

            <li>
                <a href="{URL}" class="page">{Label}</a>
            </li>

            {/block:Pages}
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

{/block:HasPages}
```

Comment: Bit of a stab in the dark but don't you need to include the bootstrap.js functions? I think you'll need to link to that. The other thing would be to get it working on a flat html file first for testing, and then try and port it to the tumblr.

Comment: @lharby is right, I looked up your source, couldn't find `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap.min.js`, you need to include one of them or just include `bootstrap-dropdown.js` if you want to save some bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it locally and added Boostrap JS from CDN, and it worked perfectly.

Just include bootstrap.js and it should work just fine.

Comment: But I couldn't understand why does that happens?